# Renaming a tar file in unix script

Tags: unix, scripting, tar

```
cd /var/opt/sw/e4/data/dev/e4_dev/DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/INPUT
for file in *;do tar -czf ../OUTPUT/"${file}".tar; done
```

According to the above code the files in input path eg. `aedlog`, `aaalog`... (file name) are placed in the output path as `aedlog.tar`, `aaalog.tar`... etc

How can i change the code such that the files are place in the output path with new name format `EDWfile_01.tar`, `EDWfile_02.tar`...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a little programming? :-)
Of course you can do it in one line using `;` and yes, it's possible to do it more compact way, but the point is in understanding, isn't it?

```
cd /var/opt/sw/e4/data/dev/e4_dev/DEVL3/EW/EWD1/DATA/AED/INPUT
no=1 ; prefix="../OUTPUT/EDWfile_" ; suffix=".tar"
for file in * ; do
  filename=$(printf "%s%02d%s" $prefix $no $suffix)
  tar -czf $filename $file
  let $((no++))
done
```

Comment: no++ getting error more tokens expected...can you help me with this?

Comment: Which OS, which shell? Well, you could use `no=$((no+1))` but probably it's just a typo. Tried using clipboard on bash on OS X and OpenBSD with ksh. On dash the second variant is needed but the error is different (and it's rather annoying shell to work with).